# VS Code Source Link

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging, sourcelink

Has anyone gotten SourceLink to work in VS Code such that it allows Go To Definition code navigation as well as debugging into the ASP.Net Source Code pulled from the Microsoft symbol servers?

I have added the following additional lines to my launch.json config:

```
            "justMyCode": false,
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
            "enableStepFiltering": false,
            "symbolOptions": {
                "searchMicrosoftSymbolServer": true,
                "searchNuGetOrgSymbolServer": true,
                "moduleFilter": {
                    "mode": "loadAllButExcluded",
                    "excludedModules": []
                }
            },
            "sourceLinkOptions": {
                "*": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
```

Debugging works really well. I see the symbols loading and I can step into all of the external source code. However, Go To Definition does not work.  I installed the latest version of the C# extension. It pulled up metadata for some of the files, which is not what I am after.  I also do not want decompiled source.  When I switched to the prerelease of the C# extension, it stopped even pulling up metadata. It seems like VS Code combined with the C# extension has all the support to do this, but I must be missing some additional setting.

Comment: Good one, following if we can get a solution.

Comment: I have the same issue: with your configuration, I can step into the code on the debugger but the Go To Definition doesn't work.